# Wifi monitor bandwidth by IP address

Tags: wireless-networking, bandwidth, airport, time-capsule

Is there a way to monitor the bandwidth being used by each IP address in my network? I'm using an apple time capsule router.

Answer (score -1):

If you're looking for a simple, user-friendly but payware (Apple-y, so to speak) solution, [NetUse](http://www.netuseapp.com/) is a mac app that should be able to do this. There are other solutions; https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1665774 discusses a method to use the open-source Cacti app to query the router in question.

Comment: Just wasted money buying NetUse...this doesn't separate traffic by IP address.